# How to parse inside redirect

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to redirect an update function

```
return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Edited successfully');
```

but i want to make it like this:

```
return redirect('/posts/{{$post->id}}')->with('success', 'Edited successfully');
```

when I am transferred to the redirected page, the URL goes like this:

```
http://myapp.dev/posts/%7B%7B$post-%3Eid%7D%7D
```

it should have been something like this:

```
http://myapp.dev/posts/9
```

Doesn't redirect parse through {{ }} ? Any suggestion for a learner like me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"` instead of `'` for php to recognize variables:

```
return redirect("/posts/{$post->id}")->with('success', 'Edited successfully');
```